# Joint Moment Generating Function Help

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

I've been working on this problem for a while and need some direction.

> $$
> f(x,y) = \left\{
> \begin{array}{lr}
> \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x} e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2}}  &  x \geq 0, -\infty < y < \infty, \\
> 0&\mbox{otherwise}\
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>
> Calculate the joint moment generating function.

My textbook hasn't been much help, but I believe the route that I should be taking involves this calculation:

$$
M_{X,Y} (t_1, t_2) = E[\exp(t_1X+t_2Y)]
$$
$$...$$
$$ = E_X(\exp(t_1X)E[\exp(t_2Y)|X])
$$

After some research I've found that it relates to the "erf" function, but this was not discussed in class or in the textbook thus I believe that a different approach is required. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$$M_{X,Y}(t_1, t_2) = {\rm E}[e^{t_1 X + t_2 Y}] = \int_{x=0}^\infty \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{t_1 x + t_2 y} e^{-x} e^{-(y-x)^2/2} \, dy \, dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

*Conditioned* on the value of $X$ being $x$, the distribution of $Y$ is a 
unit-variance normal distribution with mean $x$. So you can calculate (or
look up in your text) the (conditional) moment-generating function of $Y$.
So, now you have to calculate the expectation of something that looks like
$e^{t_1X + t_2X + t_2^2/2}$

Comment: That was a great help, thanks. Here's what I did:

$$
E(exp(t_2Y)|X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{t_2Y} f_{Y|X}(y|x)
$$
$$ = ... = exp(xt_2 + \frac{1}{2} t_2^2)$$

$$\rightarrow f_x(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x} e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2}} dy = e^{-x}$$

$$ ...  MGF = \frac{e^{\frac{t_2^2}{2}}}{1-t_1-t_2}$$